# Tools to monitor traffic over HTTP/2

Tags: monitoring, http, debugging

Normally when debugging I am using [fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler/fiddler4) to monitor traffic over HTTP.

Since [HTTP/2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) comes out binary and most implementations (Chrome, Firefox) are TLS encrypted what are my options to see what gets transferred over the wire?

One option that I have found is [Wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/HTTP2) - it is somewhat very 'big gun', I am looking for something 'lighter' like fiddler.

Comment: Do you need to monitor traffic to/from your machine only, or also other machines on the network?

Comment: @Undo only to debug on local.